# Como realizar update do nome de uma imagem no banco?

Tags: php, mysql

Esse meu script é para inserir o nome da imagem no banco, está funcionando normalmente

**INSERIR.PHP**

```php
  if ($_POST){

    $imagem = $_FILES['img_post'];
    $nomeImg = $imagem['name'];
    $tmpImg = $imagem['tmp_name'];
    $formatoBase = explode('.',$nomeImg);
    $formato = end($formatoBase);           //jesus
    $nomeImg = "paranoid_img_".uniqid().".".$formato;

        $titulo = $_POST['titulo_post'];
        $descricao = $_POST['descricao_post'];
        $texto = $_POST['texto_post'];
        $autor = $_SESSION['nome']." ".$_SESSION['sobrenome'];
        $url = uniqid();
        $pastaImg = "../img/posts";

        $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "insert into tbl_post (titulo_post, descricao_post, img_post, texto_post, autor_post, idautor_post, data_post, url_post)
                                        values ('$titulo','$descricao','$nomeImg','$texto','$autor','$id_user','$data','$url')");

        if ($query){

            $uploadPasta = move_uploaded_file($tmpImg, $pastaImg."/".$nomeImg);
            echo "<script>alert('Post enviado!');location.href=('../painel_adm.php');</script>";

        } else {

            echo "<script>alert('Erro!');location.href=('../upload_post.php');</script>";

        }
}
```

Agora eu não consigo realizar o update do nome caso eu suba outra imagem pelo formulário de alteração.

**ALTERAR.PHP**

```php
$query1 = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from tbl_post where url_post = '$url'");
$contSql=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);

if ($_POST){

    $id = $contSql['id_post'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo_post'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao_post'];
    $texto = $_POST['texto_post'];
  $imagem = $_FILES['img_post'];
    $nomeImg = $imagem['name'];
    $tmpImg = $imagem['tmp_name'];




    $query2 = mysqli_query($conexao,"update tbl_post set titulo_post='$titulo', descricao_post='$descricao', texto_post = '$texto' img_post='$nomeImg' where id_post = $id");

    if ($query2){
        echo "<script>alert('Post atualizado!');location.href='show_post.php?url=$url';</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Erro!');</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Mostra algum erro? Já verificou se todos os dados estão chegando corretamente no PHP? Testou o SQL em outro lugar pra ter certeza que está funcionando? Me parece que o problema está nessa linha `$id = $contSql['id_post'];`, o valor do id está correto?

Comment: Está sim Guilherme, se eu retiro o update da imagem, as informações sobem normal, se eu coloca, só aperece o alert de erro que coloquei no else caso a $query não fosse executada corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Consegui guys, segue o código pra quem precisar de ajuda

```html
 <?php
    if ($_POST){

    $id = $contSql['id_post'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo_post'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao_post'];
    $texto = $_POST['texto_post'];
    if(isset($_FILES['img_post']['name']) && ($_FILES['img_post']     ['name']!="")) {
    $temp = $_FILES['img_post']['tmp_name'];
    $nomeImg = $_FILES['img_post']['name'];
    unlink("img/posts/$old_image");
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "img/posts/$nomeImg");
    }
    else {
      $nomeImg = $old_image;
    }

      $query2 = mysqli_query($conexao,"update tbl_post set               titulo_post='$titulo', descricao_post='$descricao',               img_post='$nomeImg', texto_post = '$texto' where id_post = $id");

    if ($query2){

      echo "<script>alert('Post atualizado!');location.href='show_post.php?url=$url';</script>";
    } else {
      echo "<script>alert('Erro!');</script>";
    }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Fazer um update no nome da imagem no banco não requer que se mova um arquivo! A pergunta não está clara o suficiente e a resposta idem. Talvez quisesse dizer update no banco pelo nome da nova imagem movida. Outra coisa, quem é `$old_image`

Comment: Requer sim... Não estou somente dando update no nome da imagem, estou substituindo por outra, logo, tenho que remover a imagem antiga da pasta e mover a nova, acho que se eu tivesse dito que queria mudar a imagem no banco ficaria mais claro. Ah, `$old_image`, esqueci de citar aqui porque defini no head, eu atribui à essa variavel, a imagem que eu puxo do banco. `$old_img=$row['img_post'];`. Abraços Leo.